# Multithreading with condution var and mutex = system err

Tags: c++

I want to create a class that has a worker (consumer) thread that receives a notification from another thread (producer) via an interface (set_x() function) to execute its instructions.

For this I want to use a common mutex and a common cond_var.

Unfortunately the program crashes directly with the error message *std::system_error invalid argument*.

In the debugger I could see that this happens on the first access to *std::unique_lockstd::mutex mlock(set_x_mtx);* in the *void foo::output()* function.

However, I can't figure out what the problem is here?
I have created a very simplified example from my code.

My Class:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>   
#include <condition_variable>
#include <bitset>   

class foo {

    public:
        foo();
        int startUp();
        void set_x(const unsigned int bit_no, const bool state);
        

    private:

        bool x[10];
        bool run;

        std::mutex set_x_mtx;
        std::condition_variable set_x_cond;
        std::thread start_output_capture;
        std::thread consumer;

        void output();
};

foo::foo()
{
    run = false;
}

void foo::set_x(const unsigned int bit_no, const bool state)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(set_x_mtx);
    x[bit_no] = state;
    lock.unlock();
    set_x_cond.notify_one();
}

void foo::output()
{
    bool (&ref_x)[10] = x;
    consumer = std::thread([this, &ref_x]
    {
        std::bitset<10> buffer_x = 0;
        std::bitset<10> state_x = 0;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(set_x_mtx);
        set_x_cond.wait(mlock);
        while(run) 
        {
            if(buffer_x.any())
            {
                for(uint16_t idx = 0; idx < 10; ++idx)           // Navigate through mask bit by bit
                {
                    if(buffer_x[idx] != state_x[idx])            // Bit status is different
                    {
                        if(buffer_x[idx])                        // should be ON
                        {
                            state_x.flip(idx);                   // Toggle bit in current status
                        }                      
                    } else {
                        state_x.flip(idx);                       // Toggle bit in current status
                    }   
                }           
            }else {                                             
                state_x.reset();                                // Clear all bits
            }                                                                                                           
            mlock.unlock();
        }
    });
    consumer.join();
}

int foo::statUp()
{
    run = true;
    start_output_capture = std::thread([this]
    {
        output();
    });

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Main:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#include "foo.hpp"

int main()
{
    foo test;
    test.startUp();

    while(1)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(250));   
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: `foo test();` doesn't define an object; it declares a function taking no parameters and returning a `foo` object. That should be `foo test;` And class `foo` has no method called `startUp`; it's called `statUp`. Details matter. There is also no implementation of `foo:foo` to be seen, and `return;` in `main` isn't even legal.

Comment: I think you unlock the mutex within the `while`-loop multiple times. Try to use `lock-guard` wherever possible. Much less prone for programming errors and simpler to use. You can introduce blocks { } anywhere within your function.

Comment: @WhozCraig, Ok thats some important points which I have adjusted.

Comment: `set_x` is never called, You should remove the code that is not used from the question, otherwise people will get confused and look at issues in parts which you are not asking about. Checkout what is a [mcve].

Comment: @hyde Yes I know, I commented the function out for error analysis and still it comes to system:error crash. 
This should clarify my problem

Comment: @Sebastian I think i unlock the mutex at the end of the while loop, but will try it with lock-guard

Comment: @zombieanfuehrer you lock it once outside before and unlock it multiple times?

Comment: No, I have annotated this mutex everywhere except at this point and in the attributes declaration of the class. 

I just created a new mutex with a new name - out of desperation - and now it works :0 

All other program parts which were programmed after the same scheme - only in other threads had also worked. 

Very strange, I use the gcc 4.7.3 (qcc) for QNX 6.6 target maybe there is a problem here too well now it works ..... but very unsatisfactory